# Obtaining a hidden column value from the selected row in a Telerik RadGridView

Tags: visual-studio-2010, telerik, radgridview

How do I obtain the selected row value for a hidden column in a Telerik RadGridView? The column is hidden on the aspx page and I would like to retrieve the value on the client side (JavaScript).

Essentially, I want to display a name in the grid view and be able to retrieve a value from the hidden field "ID" to bring up an edit form.

Here is an example of how I'm hiding the RadGridView column.

code sample:

```
    onKeyPressEvent(sender, args) { 
  var variable = function (e) { 
    e = e || window.event; 
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
      var PartyID = args.getDataKeyValue("PARTY_ID"); 
      var oManager = '<%=winMgr.ClientID %>';
      var oManager = window.radopen("AttorneyEdit.aspx?PARTY_ID=" + PartyID, null); 
      oManager.setSize(1000, 530); 
      //Width, Height oManager.center(); 
      } else { return true; 
      } 
  } 
  theForm.onkeypress = variable 
}
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you're going the wrong way. There is a property called "[ClientDataKeyNames](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/telerik.web.ui-telerik.web.ui.gridtableview-clientdatakeynames.html)" on the mastertableview. You can add several key separated by a comma in this property. Then you'll be able to get your value without adding an extra column.

You should do something like this:

```
 function onKeyPressEvent(sender, args) { 
    if (args.get_keyCode() == 13) {
        var dataItem=sender.get_selectedItems()[0];
        var PartyID = dataItem.getDataKeyValue("PARTY_ID"); 
        var oManager = '<%=winMgr.ClientID %>';
        var oManager = window.radopen("AttorneyEdit.aspx?PARTY_ID=" + PartyID, null); 
        oManager.setSize(1000, 530); 
        //Width, Height oManager.center(); 
        } 
        else { 
          return true; 
        } 
 }
```

good luck

Comment: @lnu Great, it's working for double click events now but, not for onkeypress events. It doesn't seem to be passing the ID number in the args. Any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: Can you please elaborate? do you have any code to show with the onkeypress event?

Comment: @lnu I'm going to break this into to multiple posts due to length restrictions...                                                   function onKeyPressEvent(sender, args) 
    {
                var variable = function (e)
                {
                    e = e || window.event;

                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        var PartyID = args.getDataKeyValue("PARTY_ID");
                        var oManager = '<%=winMgr.ClientID %>';

Comment: var oManager = window.radopen("AttorneyEdit.aspx?PARTY_ID=" + PartyID, null);
                        oManager.setSize(1000, 530); //Width, Height
                        oManager.center();                      
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
    theForm.onkeypress = variable
    }

Comment: It won't work like you did: you replace the form.onkeypressevent with the function but the event must be fired from the radgrid or you won't get the args parameter. Why do you need to handle the keypressevent on the form and not in the grid like this " <ClientSettings>
            <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick" OnKeyPress="onKeyPressEvent" />
        </ClientSettings>"

Comment: @lnu The JavaScript function onKeyPressEvent is being fired by the grid like you mentioned (<ClientSettings> <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick" OnKeyPress="onKeyPressEvent" /> </ClientSettings>") Therefore the event is firing anytime a key is pressed while the grid has focus. I then check for an "Enter key press" by checking for a key code equal to 13. This keeps the functionality of the arrow keys working allowing the user to cycle through each record before bring up the edit form.  Any other thoughts?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: have you seen this article: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-navigation-with-arrow-keys.aspx

Comment: @lnu Thanks again for your continued help on this issue. I had not seen this article before although, it seems to be referring more to how key pressed events are handled. my key press event logic is working correctly. The arrow keys are capable of moving through the records and the enter key opens the edit page. I just need the key press event to pass the same arguments as the double click event. So that I can retrieve the value in the ID field with this logic, args.getDataKeyValue("ID"); Any other idea's?

Comment: but you don't need an "args parameter". If you look at my sample, I get the value using the sender which is the grid. But you could also do something like: $find('mygridclientid').get_selectedItems()[0]. It would also work, no?

Comment: Yeah your right, it's working great now. Thanks for all your help @lnu, it is much appreciated!

Comment: Hey @lnu, I'm getting "Error: 'onKeyPressEvent' is undefined". I'm using the code you posted above and calling it like this (OnKeyPress="onKeyPressEvent") from the RadGridView. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've tested the script with this code: " <ClientSettings>
            <ClientEvents OnKeyPress="onKeyPressEvent" />
        </ClientSettings>"

Comment: @lnu I think the issue I had was due to my JavaScript being located in the main content tag rather than the page header tag. I'm now having an issue with control focus. When the user enters search criteria in a text box and clicks the enter key, the control focus moves to the grid view. The arrow keys allow the user to navigate through the records and the enter key brings up a edit page. But, for some reason the first time they do this the grid view also sorts data causing it to refresh and the edit page disappears. It seems to keep the focus on the first column of the grid view. Any thoughts?